# I make an action editor animation using keyframes, I save and quit, then when I open it back up, my animations are gone

Tags: animation, armature, edit-mode, keyframes, saving

I am making an animation using Action Editor and key frames, I then go to save and quit, when I go back in, most of my animations are gone and only a few remain.

Answer (score 0):

Any action that is not assigned to an object is automatically deleted by the garbage collector after a certain amount of time.

To prevent any of your unused actions from disappearing, use the <kbd>Fake User</kbd> feature (shield icon) to permanently **keep** the certain action in your blend-file's data memory.

[image]